# CodeIgniter multiple results from stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one stored procedure on MySQL, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_multiple_results()
BEGIN
  SELECT 'A' AS A;
  SELECT 'B' AS B;
  SELECT 'C' AS C;
END
```

So, How I get the data using the query method of CodeIgniter?

```
$this->db->query('CALL get_multiple_results()')->result_array();
```

Thanks!

Comment: that looks right, are you using mysql or mysqli for the db driver?

Comment: Hi skrilled, I'm using mysqli

Comment: Document:http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/73714/

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, With the thread on Ellislab allows me to understand the DB class of CodeIgniter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oscar you should remove the answer from your question and write it as an answer, then accept it.

Comment: Also you should make your own library which would extend the existing libraray. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html scroll to: Replacing Native Libraries with Your Versions

Answer (score 5):

just call the method written below and get the array (list) of your query results e.g.
$resultSet = $this->GetMultipleQuery(" CALL my_proc ('$input')");

Query string can also be concatenation of multiple select queries.

```
     /**
     * To get result(s) of queries that returns multiple result sets...
     *
     * @author Pankaj Garg <garg.pankaj15@gmail.com>
     *
     * @param string $queryString
     *
     * @return bool|array List of result arrays
     */
public function GetMultipleQueryResult($queryString)
{
    if (empty($queryString)) {
                return false;
            }

    $index     = 0;
    $ResultSet = array();

    /* execute multi query */
    if (mysqli_multi_query($this->db->conn_id, $queryString)) {
        do {
            if (false != $result = mysqli_store_result($this->db->conn_id)) {
                $rowID = 0;
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $ResultSet[$index][$rowID] = $row;
                    $rowID++;
                }
            }
            $index++;
        } while (mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id));
    }

    return $ResultSet;
}
```

Comment: yea this is a very great solution

Answer (score 4):

I hope you are using sqlsrv driver.

In that case include library provided below.

```
$this->load->library('sqldb');
```

and run the query

```
$this->sqldb->query($querystring);

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 


/**
 * CodeIgniter sqldb Class
 *
 * This library will help get multiple resultsets from SQL stored procedure

 * @author       Saamit Raut
 */

class Sqldb {

    function __construct() {
        //$CI->load->database();
        //$this->load->library('database');

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();
    }

    public function query($querystring){
        $query=sqlsrv_query($this->CI->db->conn_id,$querystring);//exit;

        $resultsets=array();

        do{
                $array=array();
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
                    $array[]=$row;
                }
                $resultsets[]=$array;

        }while(sqlsrv_next_result($query));

        return $resultsets;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Solved my problem according to the PHP Manual
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

And, Modified the next files:

- system/database/drivers/DB_result.PHP

Add the function multi_results at the end of the file.

```
public function multi_results() { return array(); }
```

- system/database/drivers/DB_driver.php

Add the function multi_query() after the simple_query() function.

```
function multi_query($sql, $binds = FALSE)
{
    if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        $this->initialize();
    }

    $sql = $this->compile_binds($sql, $binds);

    return $this->_execute_multi_query($sql);
}
```

- system/databse/drivers/mysqli_driver.php

Add the function _execute_multi_query() after the _execute() function.

```
/**
 * Execute multi query
 *
 * @access private called by the base class
 * @param  string an SQL query
 * @return resource
 */
function _execute_multi_query($sql)
{
    $sql         = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    $result_sets = array();
    $k           = 0;

    mysqli_multi_query($this->conn_id, $sql);

    do
    {
        $result = mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id);

        if($result)
        {
            $l = 0;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $result_sets[$k][$l] = $row;
                $l++;
            }

            $k++;

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    while(mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id));

    return $result_sets;
}
```

If I missing something or something is bad, please correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not edit core files, because for each CI update you will be missed the changes. My suggestion is to extends the core files using the `application/core` folder. That is, just a suggestion!

Comment: @manix do you have the time to post your suggestion as an answer?  I'd REALLY love to see it.

Comment: Well, tonight I can create and example. Remember me by tomorrow at night.